# Uniform integrability, book

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, uniform-integrability

I search about this theme, in the books is as exercise. But I want some more theory.

What book recommend?

Comment: Joseph Diestel's [*Uniform Integrability: An introduction*](http://www.openstarts.units.it/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10077/4777/DiestelRendMat23.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Diestel's book [Uniform integrability, An introduction](http://www.openstarts.units.it/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10077/4777/DiestelRendMat23.pdf?sequence=1) is a good reference. It contains well-written theory: it's both rigorous and intuitive.